# The inconsistency between the Parser in CoreNLP and the standalone Stanford Parser

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

Just found an inconsistency issue that the parsing results of the Parser in CoreNLP and the standalone Stanford Parser are different.

For example, given a sentence "Microsoft released Windows 10.".

The Parser in CoreNLP (http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process) will give the following result:
[image]
​
However, the standalone Stanford Parser (http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) will give the following result:
[image]

​I also tried to run the codes on my machines. Both the parsers used the same model trained on the same date (englishPCFG.ser.gz, 2015-01-29). But the results given by the two parsers are still different. I tried several other sentences, and it looks that the standalone parser gives better results.

Anyone has idea on this?

Comment: https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/parser-user/2011-October/001345.html looks like the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser output can be different depending on whether you run it on a part-of-speech tagged sentence or not.

See the [Parser FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#corenlpdiff) for more information.